# C# convert kronor to dollar console program

Tags: c#, console-application

I have started to learn C#. I have created a console program that converts Swedish Kronor to USD.

I have set the conversion rate to that 1$ is equal to 13 SEK.

When I run my code I get the answer 0$ always.

```
public class övn5
{
        //double Result;
        double Dollar;
        int DollarRate = 11;

        //int Pund;
        //int PundRate = 13;

        public double SekToDollar(int Sek)
        {
            return Dollar = Sek / DollarRate;
        }

        public void ConvertCurrency()
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("Set Sek");
            int Sek = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Dollar: {0}", SekToDollar((int)Sek));
        }
}
```

and in my main:

```
class MainClass
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            övn5 o5 = new övn5();
            o5.ConvertCurrency();
        }
}
```

What have I missed in the above code?

Comment: Instead of return Dollar = Sek / DollarRate; try return Sek / DollarRate;

Comment: Tried that previously, Still getting Dollar: 0 :(

Comment: try this:
return Dollar = (double)Sek / DollarRate;

Comment: You're doing integer division and casting the result up to `double`. You should keep all your variables in the same type for this calculation. Also, you should get in the habit of using `decimal` for financial values.

Comment: The assignment that golobich suggested removing is okay; it's just pointless.

Comment: enter a number between 11 and 21, it should print "Dollar: 1"

Comment: Look up decimal. The 'M' stands for Money !

Answer (score 5):

> What have I missed in the above code?

you're expecting double from integer division
you can simply fix it by:

```
public double SekToDollar(int Sek)
{

    return (double)Sek / DollarRate;
}
```

keep in mind that you should use `decimal` for financial values/calculations etc. as madreflection said